# Not able to print a document

Tags: c#, printing

One of the methods i used :

```
                PrintDocument doc = new PrintDocument();
                doc.PrinterSettings.PrinterName = "printername";

                string[] files = Directory.GetFiles("D:\\Invoice");
                foreach (string file in files)
                {
                    string fname = Path.GetFileName(file);
                    doc.DocumentName = fname;
                    doc.Print();
                    Console.WriteLine(file);
                }
```

This gives an exception on the doc.Print() line.

> "Settings to access printer 'printername' are not valid."

The other method i used :

```
                Process printJob = new Process();
                printJob.StartInfo.FileName = @"C:\Program Files (x86)\Adobe\Reader 10.0\Reader\AcroRD32.exe";
                printJob.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
                printJob.StartInfo.Verb = "Print";
                printJob.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
                printJob.StartInfo.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
                printJob.StartInfo.Arguments = "\"" + printerAddress + "\"";
                string[] files = Directory.GetFiles("D:\\Invoice");
                foreach (string file in files)
                {
                    string fname = Path.GetFileName(file);
                    printJob.StartInfo.WorkingDirectory = Path.GetDirectoryName(fname);
                     printJob.Start();

                    //Console.WriteLine(fname);
                }
```

This gives an error after printJob.Start(). As it is pdf file, it opens the Adobe reader and displays the error message there. Hopw it explains.

> "There was an error opening the document. The file could not be found."

Can anyone help me on these issues?

Comment: Improve the question, please. Stack trace of exception, and indicating the line where it happens in your code (line number in stack trace will not tell which line it is in your code snippet). And the "error", where is it printed, or is it an exception too? What file is not found?

Comment: @hyde added the details you asked me to.. Can you plz help ?

Answer (score 0):

In 2nd snippet, this seems wrong:

```
string fname = Path.GetFileName(file);
printJob.StartInfo.WorkingDirectory = Path.GetDirectoryName(fname);
printJob.Start();
```

You just set `WorkingDirectory`. How does `printJob` get the actual file name?

---

In 1st snippet, you are probably not setting everything. Have you checked [the MSDN documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.printing.printdocument.printersettings.aspx?cs-lang=csharp)? It's generally a good idea to try to find, then read and try to understand the docs, before asking at SO...